# xs:simpleType restricted to a xs:string of a length of either n characters or m characters

Tags: xml, xsd

**I would like for a string to have two possible lengths: either *10* or *13*.**

I tried using `xs:restriction` together with `xs:enumeration` and `xs:length` but this does not work.

I am sure I am missing something obvious. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like following?

```
<xs:simpleType name="string_10_13">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value=".{10}|.{13}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

It should be more precise (e.g. to eliminate white spaces etc.) but it could be a way.

Without regex following could work:

```
<xs:simpleType name="string_10">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="10" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="string_13">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="13" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="string_10_13">
    <xs:union memberTypes="string_10 string_13"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks Jirka. I had thought about a regex but I was pretty sure there was a more robust way using "built-in" features of xml schema...

Comment: I think I found another way - I improved the answer.

Comment: Excellent: I was not aware of this xs:union tag. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real requirement here is to support ISBNs, which can be 10 or 13 characters long. But ISBNs have other constraints, which you might want to represent in the simple type as well (in XSD 1.1, you could even use an assertion to enforce correct check digits...). So I would tend to define two types ISBN-10 and ISBN-13, and then have a union type with these as their member types.

Comment: Ah well, guessing the real problem from the information given is part of the game, and you have to be prepared to guess wrong...

Comment: No problem Michael. Thanks for your input anyway!